# Has anyone been able to get WebGL EXT_disjoint_timer_query working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I want to experiment with the WebGL EXT_disjoint_timer_query, accourding to the Chromestatus site this should be available from Chrome 47 if you enable draft extensions:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6254718426808320

I have enabled --enable-webgl-draft-extensions and the equivalent in chrome://flags, but my WebGL implementation always returns null to gl.getExtension('EXT_disjoint_timer_query');

This is on windows 7, with an Nvidia 660, tried various Chrome versions (beta, dev and stable).

Has anyone actually been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not currently support EXT_disjoint_timer_query on Windows because the OpenGLES backend on Windows, ANGLE, does not support it yet. Support is currently being worked on however. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=657.